# Use of undefined constant CURL_POSTFIELDS - assumed 'CURL_POSTFIELDS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: laravel, curl, post, sms, undefined

I'm writing a laravel application to send sms. However the postfields part is throwing an error. How do I resolve it?

```php
private function sendMessage($message, $recipients) {
    $encodeMessage=urlencode($message);
    $authkey = 'XYZ';
    $senderid = '';
    $route = ;
    $country = ;
    $data = array(
        'authkey' => $authkey,
        'recipients' => $recipients,
        'message' => $encodeMessage,
        'sender' => $senderid,
        'route' => $route,
        'country' => $country,
    );
    //dd($recipients)
    $url = " ";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURL_POSTFIELDS => $data
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);$output=curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'error '.curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return back()->with('success','Messages sent successfully');
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> "Use of undefined constant CURL_POSTFIELDS - assumed 'CURL_POSTFIELDS'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: Constant is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, not `CURL_POSTFIELDS`

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that you use a constant that is undefined, which means it has never been declared. Indeed, as it has already been said in the comments, the correct constant is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because your php version dont't have the curl extension, try to change this version if you miss, or install the curl extension. To do this, run

```
sudo apt install php-version-curl
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31240425)

Answer (score -1):

```html
$fileName = storage_path('app') . '/tmp.xlsx';
$file_put_contents($fileName, file_get_contents($path));
$fields['file_name'] = $this->makeCurlFile($fileName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

protected function makeCurlFile($file)
{
   $mime = mime_content_type($file);
   $info = pathinfo($file);
   $name = $info['basename'];
   $output = new \CURLFile($file, $mime, $name);
   return $output;
}
```